# Add one click listener to two buttons, but perform different action

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

Well this is my code, for only one button, i want to have 2 buttons namely btnCalcu can someone help me? thank you all very much

```
Button btnSubmit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
} 


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home1.class);

        startActivity(intent);


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same listener for both buttons and use an `if` statement on the id of the clicked `View` to know which one the user clicked like below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        // id matches submit button's id so btnSubmit clicked.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if(v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        // id matches calculate button's id so btnCalcu clicked. 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherForm.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In your `onCreate` method get your second button and set it up the same way as you did `btnSubmit`:

```
btnCalcu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btnCalcu.setOnClickListener(this);
```